# how to set double latitude and double longitude into array

Tags: java, arrays

Hello please look at my code below.

```
        public  void onClick(View arg0)  {      
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled     
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                     String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

                    // \n is for new line

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time : " +mydate + " Your Location is - \nLat: " 
                    + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                }
```

At GPSTracker class :

```
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}
```

I want to save latitude and longitude to array.

Like when click btnShowLocation button, the latitude will be set into n1x, and its longitude n1y.

Then, the second time that button is clicked, the latitude will be set into n2x, and its longitude n2y.

Comment: Only post the relevant portions of your code.

Comment: @arshajii You tell him, I don't even bother sifting through code like this.

Comment: Where is the rest of your application?

Comment: Trim that down to something someone will actually take the time to read. You, the question asker, the person asking other people to invest *their* time into answering a question for *you*, need to invest some time up front into making your question concise, precise and to the point. You should be absorbing the brunt of the time commitment, not dumping it on us and expecting us to waste our time that you could have saved us had you done that up front investment.

Answer (score 2):

You could make an internal class called LatLong or use [simplelatlng](http://code.google.com/p/simplelatlng/)

```
public class LatLong {
  double lat;
  double long;

  public LatLong(double lat, double long) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.long = long;
  }

  public double getLat(){
    return this.lat;
  }

  public double getLong(){
    return this.long;
  }
}
```

Then you could add this to `MainActivity`

```
final List<LatLong> latLongList = new ArrayList<LatLong>();

public void onClick(View arg0) {
  //...
  double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
  double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
  latLongList.add(new LatLong(latitude, longitude));
  //...
}
```

Comment: beat me up by 10 minutes, i guess i need to write faster ;-)

Comment: I can't do this method, its contain error because my getLatitude() is different

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save one *unit of coordinates* at a time (one unit is combination of latitude and longitude), create a class holding the coordinates:

```
public class Coordinates {
    public double Latitude;
    public double Longitude;
}
```

In your activity create an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) holding elements of type Coordinates:

```
private ArrayList<Coordinates> coordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();
```

Add on every button click a new element of type Coordinates to your ArrayList:

```
var cc = new Coordinates();
cc.Latitude = lat;
cc.Longitude = lon;
this.coordinates.add(cc);
```

Later at some point where you need the coordinates just fetch them with [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) or [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) and use the coordinates:

```
Coordinates cc = (Coordinates)this.coordinates.get(position);
// cc.Latitude ...
```

This way you have a *flexible* array.